# Два разных метода в интерфейсах, но с одинаковым именем и сигнатурой

Tags: c#

Имеется 2 интерфейса и можно считать это как данность:

```
public interface IItemWrapper
{
    object GetItem();
    void ValidateItem(object item);
}

public interface IAnotherInterface
{
    void ValidateItem(object item);
}
```

Так же имеется класс, который должен реализовывать оба интерфейса. Причем, методы  `ValidateItem` и другой `ValidateItem` - разные, и оба должны реализовываться в классе, но у них одинаковое имя и signature.

Какие возможны варианты кроме переименовывания метода в одном интерфейсе?

---

PS: А, да, сам в курсе на счет [Single Responsibility Principle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Можно сказать, что неудачно придуманный пример. Но технический момент остается: Как быть если два метода двух интерфейсов имеют одинаковую сигнатуру, но сами по себе разные и оба должны быть реализованы в одном классе?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас Validate не возвращает bool а выкидывает исключение?

Comment: @AK, ну да.....

Comment: @AK    мое "ну да" относится к первому комментарию, а про второй - да выкидывает Exception

Comment: Вероятно, тогда название метода должно быть не Validate, а Assert https://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/difference-between-assert-and-verify.html

Comment: @AK, на самом деле тут не суть. Названия методов - первое, что в голову пришло. Но про Assert - может пригодится.

Comment: Эээээ. Андрей NOP стер мое вступление:   _CofeeBreak:_

Вопрос не сложный и не актуальный для меня, скорее интересно как-нибудь сейчас сделать мини перерыв и поучаствовать на SOru, но при этом не сильно отвлекаясь от своих задач. _Внизу напишу_

Comment: Мы поняли, но больше это добавлять в тело вопроса не нужно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Явно укажите названия:

```
public class SampleClass : IItemWrapper, IAnotherInterface
{
    void IItemWrapper.ValidateItem(object item)
    {
    }

    void IAnotherInterface.ValidateItem(object item)
    {
    }
}
```

Документация:

- [Explicit Interface Implementation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) - [Явная реализация интерфейса (Руководство по программированию в C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)

Comment: И как вариант - ещё написать аналогичный метод у класса, который внутри будет вызывать реализации интерфейсов например.

Comment: комментарий к ответу:    Да, точно........